# Hello Everyone. Can anyone help me how to do form error message after submit button, Here my codes I tried but i couldn't get

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

Can anyone help me how to do form  error message after submit button, Here my codes I tried but i couldn't get it.

```
 <form method="POST"  >
    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="contactName" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. John Lim" required  />
    <br />
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="contactEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required />
    <br />
    <label>Phone Number</label>
    <input type="tel" name="contactNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. +60 11111111" required />
    <label>Description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" type="text" rows="5" cols="5" name="contactDesciption" placeholder="Brieﬂy describe the bespoke talent you wish for us to identify for you in 200 words." required> </textarea>
    <button class="btn" type="submit" formmethod="post">Request Talent</button>
</form>


input:required {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
input:valid {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: This question lacks some basic info to show that you've done some research. Are you using a JavaScript framwork? What is the context, i.e. is it part of something like an ASP.NET application?

Comment: I used Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `action=""` as a form attribute if you meant to set it.

If you want to validate form data before it submits (but after the button's clicked) and post an error if that fails, use javascript/jquery to set the form's submit event to return true/false based on the validation that you write.

Returning false will prevent the form submission - then you can post an error message of your choosing onto the page.

If you submit the form with AJAX, you'll be able to output errors from after it submits like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "whatever.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { param: paramvalue },
    success: function(response){
        // do something here if successful
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

What error message(s) do you want to display? If a field is left empty? If the form could not be submitted wherever you're trying to submit it?

edit: "required" has [limited browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=required) as of Dec 2017, so a script fallback may be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I just want to show the empty field and with red border.

Comment: Use jQuery/JS to check which field(s) are empty in your function that validates the form on submit. If it finds an empty field, add a CSS class to the input that sets the border red.

Comment: It appears that the OP added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47547734/1575353) with a form tag that has the action attribute set- if I were you then I would update this answer to point that out as crucial for the built-in html5 form error messages provided my modern browsers  - and maybe only suggest using Javascript for advanced control of the message display.

Comment: Sam, forgive me if I'm misunderstanding, but do you mean having or not having the attribute is crucial for HTML5 error messages? You're right that HTML5 doesn't require it, though, so not setting it is a valid alternative. The extra spaces just gave me the impression that Raz may have meant to.

Answer (score 0):

I found the simple way it works

[image]

```
 <form method="post" action="@Url.Action("FlexyBuddy", "Emails")">
                <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="contactName" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. John Lim" required  />
                <br />
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="contactEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required />
                <br />
                <label>Phone Number</label>
                <input type="tel" name="contactNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="e.g. +60 11111111" required />
                <br />
                <label>Description</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" type="text" rows="5" cols="5" name="contactDesciption" placeholder="Brieﬂy describe the bespoke talent you wish for us to identify for you in 200 words." required> </textarea>
                <br />
                <button class="btn" type="submit">Request Talent</button>
            </form>

/*Error message styling*/ 
.form-control:focus {
     border-color:red!important;
}
```